# How this assignment and control flow of JAVASCRIPT code works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gulp

In the following code, how the statement works, as this statement is the part of an javascript file.

```
 this.isSelected = function(checkTab)
{
  return(this.tab===checkTab);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It creates an `isSelected()` method on the controller that takes a single parameter. That parameter is then compared against a `tab` property on the controller for equality and the result is returned.

Answer (score 1):

`this.isSelected` is a function, taking `checkTab` as a parameter. It compares it to `this.tab` and returns `true` if they are equal, otherwise `false`.

```
this.isSelected = function(checkTab)
{
    return (this.tab === checkTab);
}

// equivalent to
function isSelected(checkTab) {
    if(this.tab === checkTab) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: In the above statement CheckTab is a variable or keyword